# Why can't I use || OR Operator in C++ Switch statement?

Tags: c++, syntax

I've been working with VB.NET for years and I luv the language. Now dispersing myself into C++ I'm having a tough time to grasp the logics of C++.

Kindly tell me any workaround. Thanks a lot !

Comment: That doesn't make sense.. How do you want to use `||` in `switch`?

Comment: *This question appears to be offtopic because it is just a rant instead of elaborating what the user really wants to do with some code examples of what he tried*

Comment: Are you trying `switch(x) { case 0: case 1: /*this is an or */ break; case 3: break; }` ?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: `case 42: if( a || b ) { ... ` ? ^^

Comment: instead of `||` you can specify multiple conditions in a switch case e.g. `case 1: case2: break;`

Comment: Your question makes no sense, please re-phrase it and don't give subjective remarks about the language such as '"ill-logical" logics of C++' just because you do not understand it.

Comment: Because there is not a reason. DIfferent languages and different syntax (for example complex switch expressions also in C# aren't allowed).

Comment: @PlasmaHH I thought he wanted to use it **in** `switch`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: `switch(foo) { case 42: if( a || b ) { ...` ? ^^

Comment: @PlasmaHH Again..... I though `switch(something || somethingElse)`. His title is confusing.

Comment: Take a look also to this duplicate (C# instead of C++ but same concept): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744845/converting-from-vb-to-c-sharp/20744943#20744943

Comment: @Adriano: actually, there's an historical reason - `switch` was born as a way to make the compiler generate a jump table, hence the labels (and the fall through), the limitation to exact match and the constraint of integral types only.

Comment: @MatteoItalia for C (and for all languages with C-style syntax because of LAP) I completely agree.

Comment: While the absence of question marks hints that there is no clear question, I would assume that the intention is: *I cannot do `||` in a case in C++ like in VB, is there a similar construct?*

Answer (score 4):

That is quite an unclear question, but you are probably asking why you cannot do this:

```
switch(mynumber) { //assuming an int here
  case 1:
    printf("Something.");
    break;
  case 2 || 3: 
    printf("Something else.");
    break;
 }
```

This will not work as you expected: the || operator in C++ will actually do `2 || 3`, evaluating to `1`. Instead, you can replicate your case statements:

```
switch(mynumber) {
  case 1:
    printf("Something.");
    break;
  case 2: 
  case 3: 
    printf("Something else.");
    break;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like VB.NET supports expression in case statements while C++ does not.

Comment: This actually answers the question :)

Comment: I'm not sure.  It does support expressions in case labels: `#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 const bool y = false, z = true;
 switch (42) { case 41+(y||z): printf("42\n"); }
 return 0;
}` - they just have to be compile time constants.